# FBSDKGraphRequest does not get email address

Tags: swift3, facebook-login

I need to get user data from Facebook after login, with this code, I can only get id and name but not email.

```
func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!){

    if error != nil{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start { (connection, result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Failed to start graph request:", err)
            return
        }
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: And where are you asking the user for the necessary permission?

Comment: in the viewDidLoad, `loginButton.readPermissions = ["email", "public_profile"]` Is this enough?

Comment: Have you verified the user granted the `email` permission? (By debugging the access token, or calling /me/permissions with it.) Does the user have a verified e-mail address set in their profile?

Comment: I tried many different version of my code. When I put /me/permissions that didnt give even id and name. I hate to ask this but do you have and sample of this?

Comment: _“When I put /me/permissions that didnt give even id and name”_ - well it is not supposed to, why would it ... it is supposed to list the permissions the user has actually granted to your app.